# IBM MobileFirst Plugin should use a background thread

Tags: objective-c, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM's MobileFirst Platform Foundation (6.3.0.00-20150130-1638) to build an Android and iOS application. The application (iOS at this moment) gives quite a lot of information when running. But one is quite common and I think it is also quite dangerous. The error I get is:

```
THREAD WARNING: ['WLApp'] took '11.354004' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

This is for WLApp, but for more plugins like DeviceAuth (111.884766 ms), UserAuth (19.232910 ms), another DeviceAuth (47.208984 ms) and more.

Is there a way to run plugins on the background, and so, how can I achieve this?

Another question is if I can and how to hide the Debug notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this on your own with the supplied plug-ins.
These warnings are issued by iOS but are harmless.

We'll take a look, but this is harmless, unless you actually see a real problem (which I doubt right now that you do).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, we don't have any problems right now. The only reason I thought this was dangerous is because Apple dislikes applications which blocks the main thread, but if it is harmless, it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

These warnings come from cordova plugins, and it is harmless, it just means that the code in the executing part of the cordova native plugin side, should be run in background.

We are intending on cleaning these warnings out.

look at: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can't modify the plugin calls as they are in the read-only files. If this will be fixed in the future, it would be nice!